# How do I request the migration a Question to another Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Should [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/why-did-some-people-need-to-pay-a-bond-in-the-1700s-in-order-to-get-married/3112#3112) be migrated to the new Genealogy Stack Exchange?.

It is a Genealogy question but at the time of asking the Genealogy Exchange did not exist.

Comment: Actually, I think it would be a good fit in either location. Rather than migrate it, I would suggest asking it again over there. You may get a different kind of response.

Comment: @Steven Drennon  yes, i was thinking along these lines myself, however I am totally satisfied with answers I got here on "History". My thinking behind the OP was that those on the Genealogy stack exchange could benefit more.

Comment: In that case, you have even more of a reason to repost the question over there! You could even provide a link back to the original question here if you wanted. We usually don't migrate a question unless it is just completely out of place here, but cross posting is not uncommon.

Comment: @StevenDrennon: At some point in my SE existence, I was told that it was not a good idea to ask the same question on a bunch of different sites. What's the difference between this and "cross posting"? Or has the policy changed recently?

Comment: @TomAu Cross posting (posting exactly the same question on multiple sites) should be avoided in general. However, a recent change in migration protocol disabled migration for questions older than 60 days (even for moderators). So, given that it's technically impossible to migrate the question in question, cross posting is next available option (not sure if it's a _good_ option, I'm not familiar enough with the subject matter to know if the question should be asked on the new Genealogy site).

Comment: The old "parent" problem, them. One parent (moderator) says that X is ok, the other say not. What is a "kid" supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one ever answered this I will answer it now. You can flag a question to be reviewed by the moderators, and suggest that the question be migrated to another site.